# Select value from table sorted by a certain order from another table

Tags: mysql, sorting, sql-order-by

I want to select value from table sorted by a certain order.

I have a table called test that looks like this:

```
| date     | code      | value    |
+----------+-----------+----------+
| 20050104 | 000005.SZ | -6359.19 |
| 20050104 | 600601.SH | -7876.34 |
| 20050104 | 600602.SH | -25693.3 |
| 20050104 | 600651.SH |   NULL   |
| 20050104 | 600652.SH | -15309.9 |
...
| 20050105 | 000005.SZ | -4276.28 |
| 20050105 | 600601.SH | -3214.56 |
...
| 20170405 | 000005.SZ | 23978.13 |
| 20170405 | 600601.SH | 32212.54 |
```

Right now I want to select only one date, say date = 20050104, and then sort the data by a certain order (the order that each stock was listed in the stock market).

I have another table called stock_code which stores the correct order:

```
+---------+-----------+
| code_id | code      |
+---------+-----------+
|       1 | 000002.SZ |
|       2 | 000004.SZ |
|       3 | 600656.SH |
|       4 | 600651.SH |
|       5 | 600652.SH |
|       6 | 600653.SH |
|       7 | 600654.SH |
|       8 | 600602.SH |
|       9 | 600601.SH |
|      10 | 000005.SZ |
...
```

I want to sorted the selected data by stock_code(code_id), but I don't want to use join because it takes too much time. Any thoughts?

I tried to use field but it gives me an error, please tell me how to correct it or give me an even better idea.

```
select * from test 
    where date = 20050104 and code in (select code from stock_code order by code)
    order by field(code, (select code from stock_code order by code));

Error Code: 1242. Subquery returns more than 1 row
```

Answer (score 2):

You told us that you don't want to join because it takes too much time, but the following join query is probably the best option here:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM test t
INNER JOIN stock_code sc
    ON t.code = sc.code
WHERE t.date = '20050104'
ORDER BY sc.code_id
```

If this really runs slowly, then you should check to make sure you have indices setup on the appropriate columns.  In this case, indices on the `code` columns from both tables as well as an index on `test.date` should be very helpful.

```
ALTER TABLE test ADD INDEX code_idx (code)
ALTER TABLE test ADD INDEX date_idx (date)
ALTER TABLE code ADD INDEX code_idx (code)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, after indexing does hepls a lot, but every time I add the indices it takes around 60 seconds......since my table has around 9000000 rows and I have thousands of table just like that...... A little unbearable......

Comment: @DirkPaul But how often do you plan on updating the table?